# Open server: Object not found!

Tags: openserver

Здравствуйте! Перестали загружаться все домены на Open server, даже локалхост. Ввожу http://localhost - загружается просто белый экран, ввожу http://localhost/info.html / http://localhost/info.php - выдает [такое](https://gyazo.com/14ca0cf156c6037a67999465a332379e). А апач выводит ерор:

```
[:error] [pid 7028:tid 816] [client 127.0.0.1:2336] script 'C:/OpenServer/modules/system/html/default/info.php' not found or unable to stat
```

И самое главное, захожу в пхпмайадмин и все [работает](https://gyazo.com/a8a53c589e63b5ffef6498aff318a00c)!

В конфигах только переключал версии апача и пхп, но все работало, а сейчас ни при каких настройках не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, хоть в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего неправильно настроены привилегии для файла `hosts`, в папке *Windows* и *Open Server* не может достучаться к нему.

Посмотрите в свойствах, разрешена ли запись в файл или попробуйте переустановить *Open Server* по [инструкции](http://readanduse.com/2016/09/10/kak-ustanovit-nastroit-zapustit-open-server-instruktsiya/) , возможно поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблему удалось решить только переустановкой Open Server. Сразу все заработало без проблем